# Kunernetes/kustomize Service endpoints abnormal behavior

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

We're using kustomize with kubernetes on our project.

I'm trying to implement access to external service using IP as mentioned in this link

https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-access-external-services-e4fd643e5097

Here's my service

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pgsql
spec:
  ports:
   - protocol: TCP
     port: 5432
     targetPort: 5432
     name: "pg"
  selector: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: pgsql
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 1.1.1.1
    ports:
      - port: 5432
        name : "pg"
```

When I apply with kubectl command (kubectl apply -k ...) I have a warning

> Warning: kubectl apply should be used on resource created by either
> kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply

However, this warning does not avoid endpoints and service creation.

> kubectl get endpoints

```
NAME                ENDPOINTS           AGE
pgsql               172.12.xx.yy:5432   3m27s
```

**Unfortunately, the ip address is different from the one I put in my yml (1.1.1.1)**

If I apply a second time

> kubectl apply -k ...

> kubectl get endpoints

```
NAME                ENDPOINTS           AGE
pgsql               1.1.1.1:5432   10s
```

I do not have the warning above anymore.

The endpoint is the one expected.

I expect endpoint address to be the exact one (1.1.1.1:5432) from the first apply.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: output of kubectl version? are you sure you did not have these resources created already by some other means before applying first time?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu, I deleted all my resources before applying the first time. i user kubectl server 1.16.4 kubectl client 1.17.2

Comment: Can you please add the `Kustomize` files to create your services to your question for others to check if they observe the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It probably comes from the empty selector. Could you try to remove it completely?
This is supposed to work only if your service doesn't have any [selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)